# Delaying a jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I've got three instanced of image sliders on a page, that are supposed to fade in a row, one after the other. I'm using innerfade.js

I wanted to have them start at different times, e.g. the first one starting after 2 sec, the 2nd one after 4 sec, the third one after 6 sec. So, the fisrt transition needs to happen after 2 secs, but then it needs to be 6 seconds until the next fade.

---

EDIT:
They're supposed to appear together at the same time when the page loads and then fade one-by-one.

---

I'm not sure how whether I can achieve this. I've tried using setTimeout as well as .delay, but I couldn't get it to work. The reason is probably that I'm no good with Javascript. But I'd appreciate some help here.

This is where I'm coming from:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('#header-img-1').innerfade2({
            animationtype: 'fade',
            speed: 750,
            timeout: 6000,
            type: 'random_start',
            containerheight: '1em'
        });

        $('#header-img-2').innerfade2({
            animationtype: 'fade',
            speed: 750,
            timeout: 6000,
            type: 'random_start',
            containerheight: '1em'
        });

        $('#header-img-3').innerfade2({
            animationtype: 'fade',
            speed: 750,
            timeout: 6000,
            type: 'random_start',
            containerheight: '1em'
        });
    }
);
```

Many thanks.

Comment: `setTimeout` should work fine. What did you try?

Comment: you can try http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: Your problem could come from your function `innerfade2`. Could you provide the code?

Comment: HERE the code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/spirelli/NAyKX/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how to use setTimeout to achieve the kind of interaction you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/zFMjf/

HTML

```
<div id="example1" class="con orange" style="display:none;">Example 1</div>
<div id="example2" class="con lime" style="display:none;">Example 2</div>
<div id="example3" class="con yellow" style="display:none;">Example 3</div>​
```

CSS

```
.con { width:200px; line-height:60px; margin:0 0 20px 0; }
.orange { background:orange; }
.lime { background:lime ; }
.yellow { background:yellow ; }
```

jQUERY

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('#example1').slideToggle();
},2000);

setTimeout(function(){  
    $('#example2').slideToggle();
},4000);

setTimeout(function(){  
    $('#example3').slideToggle();
},6000);​
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you can delay the script execution using `setTimeout` and `delay` functions.

Here is a sample of `setTimeout` usage :

```
setTimeout(function(){
        $('#header-img-2').innerfade2({
            animationtype: 'fade',
            speed: 750,
            timeout: 6000,
            type: 'random_start',
            containerheight: '1em'
        });
    },2000 /*2seconds*/);
```

About `.delay()` you should code like that :

```
$('#header-img-2').delay(2000).innerfade2({
    animationtype: 'fade',
    speed: 750,
    timeout: 6000,
    type: 'random_start',
    containerheight: '1em'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var numb = [1,2,3];

    $.each(numb, function(i,elm) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#header-img-'+numb[i]).innerfade2({
                animationtype: 'fade',
                speed: 750,
                timeout: 6000,
                type: 'random_start',
                containerheight: '1em'
            });
        },numb[i]*2000);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xXSb5/1/)

Comment: @user1154435 - my bad, forgot the `function` in `document.ready`, did'nt realize you had put it on a seperate line?

Comment: That's great. However, what I was after is for all three slideshows to display initially and but for the transitions to start one after the other. Is there a simple tweak to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try below approach, I have optimized it a little based on few assumptions.. but this will give you an idea. Let me know if it is different.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var innerFadeOpt = {
            animationtype: 'fade',
            speed: 750,
            timeout: 6000,
            type: 'random_start',
            containerheight: '1em'
        };

        var ptr = 0, headerImgs = ['#header-img-1', '#header-img-2', '#header-img-3'];

        var timer = setInterval (function () {
           if (ptr == headerImgs.length - 1) {
              clearInterval(timer);
              return;
           }

           $(headerImgs[ptr++]).innerfade2(innerFadeOpt);
        }, 2000);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi Vega (and everyone else), It look as if your code comes closest i.e. it actually does something. I've made it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/spirelli/Rca4d/   I've removed the "- 1" from the script because otherwise the third ID would not respond. Trouble is that now all images within the sliders show initially which only disappears after what is supposed to be the first transaction. --- I tink I need further help.